# Radio/genres error call in the Deezer iOS sdk

Tags: deezer

In the iOS SDK v0.9.0-beta6 the call:

```
[DZRRadio radiosByGenreWithRequestManager:self.requestManager callback:^(DZRObjectList *deezerList, NSError *error) { 
    if (error) {
        BTBLog_Error(@"Request did fail with error : %@", [error description]);
        return;
    }}];
```

results in the error:

```
Error Domain=DZRModelErrorDomain Code=3 "Some object could not be parsed" UserInfo=0x7c11f070 {DZROriginalErrorsKey=(
"Error Domain=DZRModelErrorDomain Code=2 \"The API returned a malformated object (either id or type missing)\" UserInfo=0x7ae55e80 {DZROriginalJSONKey=<CFBasicHash 0x7c1c47d0 [0x4e99528]>{type = immutable dict, count = 3,\nentries =>\n\t0 ...
```

and it logs a lot of warnings like:

```
[DZRWarning]: No "type" in the JSON object cannot parse. The object was:
{
id = 153;
radios =     (
            {
        id = 30921;
        picture = "http://api.deezer.com/radio/30921/image";
        title = Blues;
        tracklist = "http://api.deezer.com/radio/30921/tracks";
        type = radio;
    }
);
title = Blues;
}
```

Could you please tell me how to fix it? Or is maybe a bug in this SDK version?